# Faceted time series with mean profile in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

Using the following simulated time series:

```
n=70
m1 = matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=7)
m2 = matrix(rnorm(n, 0,4), ncol=7)
d = data.frame(rbind(m1,m2), cl=rep(c(1,2), each=5))
```

(first 7 columns represent the time point, last column the class)

Is it possible to construct a faceted time series that includes the mean curve in each plot, using ggplot2?

The results should look something like this:[image: plot with mean curves]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It might not be the most beautiful code, but I believe it gets you what you are looking for,

```
n=70
m1 = matrix(rnorm(n), ncol=7)
m2 = matrix(rnorm(n, 0,4), ncol=7)
d = data.frame(rbind(m1,m2), cl=rep(c(1,2), each=5))

d <- cbind(paste("d", 1:NROW(d), sep = ""), d)
names(d)[1] <- "id.var"

library(reshape)
longDF <- melt(d, id=c("cl", "id.var"))
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = longDF, aes(x = variable, y = value, group = id.var))
p + geom_line() + stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", 
se = FALSE, colour="red") + facet_grid(cl ~ .)
```

Please don't hesitate to improve my code.

[image: spaghetti plot with stat_smooth and facet_grid]

Comment: My pleasure, I know how it feels when you are stuck. You should try changing the `se = FALSE` to `se = TRUE`, I often find that information quite informative.

Comment: @Eric I was wondering if you could provide some detail about how longDF was created.  I would imagine `melt` from `reshape` was used...

Comment: @blueandgrey, somehow I messed up my own code my making it more concise. Regardless, It should be working now!

Comment: Shouldn't `stat_smooth(aes(group = 1), method = "lm", 
se = FALSE, colour="red")` rather be `stat_summary(fun.y=mean, colour="red", geom="line", aes(group=1))`. Current Solution adds a trend line over all observations but not the mean of all observations under Xi? Unsure what OP really wants but the posted image indicates a kinked red line.